# DataTable Array onto a Table Control

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, datatable, html-table

Let's say I have an array of `DataTable[]`. In each DataTable there are up to 5 rows. Each row has 5 columns. I need to display the content of the DataTable in an html table of 5 x 5, so that there is a 1 to 1 relationship between a cell from dataTable and a cell of an html table (i.e td).

Can anyone give me the piece of code on how to achieve this? It needs to loop through the length of the array of DataTable. So if there are 3 DataTables, it needs to create 3 html tables.

Example of my Datatable

```
Row 1 : Colors, Sizes, Length
Row 2 : Blue  ,   L  , 23
Row 3 : Green ,   M  , 24
Row 4 : Red   ,   S  , 25
Row 5 : Yellow,      , 26
```

Comment: Sounds like a bunch of nested loops to me.  Have you written any code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok, here is some code.  I didn't compile it so there could be typos... but I imagine it will get you going in the right direction.  3 nested loops.

```
StringBuilder html = new StringBuilder();

foreach(DataTable aTable in tableList)
{
   html.Append("<table>");

   foreach(DataRow row in aTable.rows)
   {
      html.Append("<tr>");

      foreach(string cell in row.Items)
      {
         html.Append("<td>");

         if (cell == null)
            html.Append("&nbsp;");
         else
            html.Append(cell);

         html.Append("</td>");
      }

      html.Append("</tr>");
   }

   html.Append("</table>");
}
```

Comment: That looks like this could work... i was hoping to see one loop on the no of tables since the DT are fixed size but i guess the small size wont matter much...

Comment: Thanks Hogan, I went back to basics like you suggested and got the content i needed...
For anyone else in case you wanna use this code, you'll have to make a couple of minor corrections:
1. use foreach (DataRow row in aTable.Rows) 2. check for nulls in the foreach loop for the cells of the row.

Comment: There i no row.items in ---- foreach(string cell in row.Items). .items does not exist. Whats the fix?

Comment: @icelated : did you use a lowercase `i` instead of upper case `I` (`.items` instead of `.Items`)?